# Create a new Gradle Project in Eclipse fails

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

Creating a new Gradle project fails with,
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip'.

If I click on finish then I see the problem - Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip'.
Could not determine the class-path for class org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalPhasedActionAdapter.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2020-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the following, not yet fixed **issue on macOS Big Sur**:

[**Eclipse Buildship issue #1050**: *Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution '.../gradle-6.7-bin.zip': Java home is different*](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1050)

You might comment and/or propose a patch there.